# Can foreign tourists arrive in the UK from amber list countries?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, covid-19

Current UK guidance reads: "You should not travel to amber list countries or territories for leisure purposes." I assume however that this is talking about UK citizens travelling TO amber list countries and then returning. How about foreign tourists who are currently in amber list countries? Can they apply for (and be granted) tourist (visitor) visas under the current circumstances?

Comment: What’s the reason and duration of the intended visit? People arriving from amber list counties are required to self-quarantine “at home” for 10 days, in addition to a plethora of tests, so actual “tourism” will probably be considered with a very skeptical eye, given the associated cost and inconvenience.

Comment: My spouse visiting our family and me for 4 months, staying at our home.

Comment: that is probably more likely to go through, though note that in many places embassies, consulates and visa centres are closed or have reduced processing capabilities or longer processing times, and the usual visa rules still apply (no idea what the rules are for spouses... aren’t there specific visas for that case?).

Comment: @jcaron yes there are - but in our particular situation, we will not be eligible to apply for a Spouse Visa until October or November. That is why we're hoping a Visit will suffice for now.

Comment: @marc Does your spouse have a travel history of visiting the UK? The deciding factor for a visitor visa could be whether your spouse can demonstrate ties to their country of residence sufficiently compelling to convince the ECO of their intention to leave at the end of the visit

Comment: @traveller she has visited the UK on 3 occasions in the last 3 years, the first two times for one month each. the last time she stayed for 6 months due to COVID preventing her from getting a flight (she received an extension).

Comment: @marc In that case, depending on when she was last in the UK, you may want to be careful that she does not fall foul of V4.2 (b) “will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home”

Comment: @Traveller she was last in the UK in July 2020; to clarify, I have explained our circumstances in detail in another question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163728/how-likely-is-it-that-my-wife-will-have-her-uk-visitor-visa-refused

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.